# Make a QMenu label bold without affecting its children

Tags: qt, python-2.7, qt4, pyside

I'm trying to change the styling and/or font of the label/text on the QMenu, without affecting it's children. I'm doing this in Python with PySide (which works just like Qt).

I've tried:

```
menu = QtGui.QMenu()
f = menu.font()
f.setBold(True)
menu.setFont(f)
```

And

```
menu = QtGui.QMenu()
menu.setStyleSheet("QMenu{font-weight: bold;}")
```

Both of these would not change the label of the menu itself, yet will do it on all of its children.

I would prefer to set the styling directly on the QMenu (or another class if it acts similarly and makes it possible) instead of applying a stylesheet on its parent.

**Goals**

The idea is that I have a menu with a variety of sub-menus (which are somewhat dynamic based on folders on a server) of which some need to be Bold and some Italic. Therefore I would like to add these sub QMenu's dynamically and style them accordingly.

Comment: It's not clear, Is the style sheet code currently working well for you, but you want to achieve needed effect without style sheets ?

Comment: What do you do with `menu` object after that? menu.exec or what? Where do you place it? Where do you want to see bold text?

Comment: @N1ghtLight: As stated using setStyleSheet results in the same output as adjusting the font. Both are not what I want.

Comment: @Ezee: I'm adding it to another menu as a submenu and want a variation of bold/italic submenu items and style those individually (that hold their own MenuItems, so it's a QMenu)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can achieve it easy. To understand the logic:

- `QMenu` - is a widget which displays items
- When you add `QMenu` to another `QMenu` `QMenu::menuAction` is placed in a base menu.
- If you want to customize how your submenu looks when it's added to a base menu, you need to customize the `menuAction`.

So to make you menu bold you just need to set a bold font to `menuAction` of this menu.

Here is a simple working example:

```
QMenu m; //base menu
QMenu sub; //sub menu
sub.setTitle("subMenu");

QAction* a1 = new QAction("act1", &m);
QAction* a2 = new QAction("act2", &m);
QAction* a3 = new QAction("act3", &m);

// set a bold font for a sub menu item
QFont f = sub.menuAction()->font();
f.setBold(true);    
sub.menuAction()->setFont(f);

// add an action to the sub menu
sub.addAction(a3);

// add two actions and the sub menu to the base menu
m.addAction(a1);
m.addMenu(&sub);
m.addAction(a2);

// show the base menu
m.exec(QCursor::pos());
```

Answer (score 0):

Read the Qt documentation about [QSS selectors](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html#selector-types).

For your case: you could not directly customize labels of specific menu items. But you may insert `QWidgetAction` insead of `QAction` and customize it as you want (place a label on `QWidgetAction` and customize it).

Comment: Can the QWidgetAction act as a normal 'submenu' holding children QMenuItem and QMenu?

Comment: Yes, everything depends on how you customize inner widget.

Comment: You won't get exact behavior, but you can get close to it having spent a lot of efforts.